# Check box "ticked" on page 1 is reflected in page 2 in EnhancedGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a enhancedgrid and used on two pages. When check box (component of data enhanced grid) is checked on page1, the equivalent row(s) on pg 2 are then ticked. My enhancedgrid code is

```
grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                loadingMessage:"Please wait",
                store:newStore,
                structure:layoutQL,
                autoWidth:false,
                autoHeight:true,
                columnReordering:false,
                rowsPerPage:3,
                indirectSelection: true,
                //noDataMessage:"No transactions have been processed for posting.",
                //selectionMode:'single',
                 plugins: {
                   pagination: {
                       description: true,
                       sizeSwitch: false,
                       pageStepper: true,
                       gotoButton: true,
                       /*page step to be displayed*/
                       maxPageStep: 6,
                       /*position of the pagination bar*/
                       position: "bottom",
                       indirectSelection: true  
                   },
                   filter : {
                        // Show the closeFilterbarButton at the filter bar
                        closeFilterbarButton: true,
                        // Set the maximum rule count to 5
                        ruleCount: 5,
                        // Set the name of the items
                        itemsName: "records"
                   }

              }
```

I am using EnhancedDataGrid as in dojo framework. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "grid.selection.deselectAll()" when you move from one page to the next.